A coworker is spreading rumours that another coworker is a Paedophile
Who do I contact if my hours were cut because I made an complaint to the general manager

at a minimum this need a location country (and state if US) to be answerable.

Circulating gossip is rarely looked on approvingly.

Please clarify what you complained about. Did you complain about someone being a pedophile, based on gossip you heard, or did you complain about hearing gossip about someone? Also, did your cut hours result from you being removed from shifts they are in, or were your hours cut randomly?

Did you complain about a coworker being a pedophile because you are an underaged worker of some description? What was the basis of your complaint?

Hopefully that is not your real name.

@SolarMike: "... and if you write it and you sign it, then do not be surprised by the results" :)

If the gossip is true, did the person in question serve time and is now supposed to be considered a valid citizen?

@DavidR What is the alternative, they are sex offender wanted by police?

@GregoryCurrie There are three possibilities, the person is creepy, the person is being processed by the legal system (before trial, or on probation), or the person has served time. The vast majority are on probation or have served time. In which case, the legal system has determined that this person is safe to be in public but not necessarily in a child interacting role. The probability is that the gossip is simply raising fears that do not need to be raised. Be aware, but not freak out.

I honestly don’t know or even care about what the person did if corporate hired the person it isn’t right for someone else to discuss their personal business I didn’t want to hear it and told her if she had an issue working with that person she should go to HR not tell others so

You're trying to solve the wrong problem.
Your job security right now is zero %. You need to worry about that, not your hours being cut, that's just a symptom.

How do you know that, given there is zero information in the question?

@nvoigt there's enough info to see it. Complaint + hours cut = 0% job security. Best for the OP to sort that out rather than mess around until it's too late

Or, alternatively: complaint => person taken out of the potential offenders zone of influence (their shifts) to protect them while HR investigates. You have no idea, what their job security is, with this little information.

@nvoigt alternatively =  mess around until it's too late............................ it's bread on the table... don't mess around. I've seen this several times. Haven't seen it end well except when people immediately start looking out for themselves. If the first response to a complaint is to cut hours without explanation.... it's pretty simple where that's going. Unsure what you mean about HR... I don't think HR is going to ask anyone if they're a pedo

HR might have the legal obligation to ask, depending on circumstances. It would probably be different idepending on whether the OP worked in a Kindergarden or Strip Club. Point is... we just don't know. You might be right. Or not. There is just not enough information to say.

@nvoigt not enough for you, you mean. Plenty for me though.

I followed my chain of command and spoke with my general manager about the acquisition and he said he would speak with the young lady but when you’re trying to get other people to get on board that don’t even know the person to Single out another person that isn’t right the following week my hours were cut

You provided insufficient information for a more useful answer. So here is a generic answer for a vaguely described problem.
Discuss with your direct manager about the situation. Clarify why exactly the hours were cut. Maybe you forgot to check-in in the morning, and the meeting with the general manager is irrelevant.
Once the details are clarified, discuss how things can be improved. I am looking at least at two outcomes:

have the cut hours added back in;
clarify how to proceed in the future in order to avoid such a mess.

Most likely, you need to NOT act based on gossip. If you complain about something, you need to have solid proof. However, even hard evidence does not guarantee your safety. Countless people "were suicided" throughout the history - exactly because they knew too much.
While your enthusiasm and morality might be well meant, the acting on them might not have been recommended.

I talked with the person who was spreading these rumours but she kept talking about it with the company new hires so that’s why I went to my general manager I didn’t go to HR until my hours were cut

This Question is the definition of confused.

As of 9/9 in the AM the OP seems to be using their real name. (Please change it for your own sake.)
No location information
Serious allegation - seemingly based on a third party? AKA gossip?
Biggest stated concern is OP's hours have been reduced.

IMHO - If the OP has a reason to believe the allegations are true, GO TO THE POLICE! Don't spew it as gossip.
If there is HR - go there. If there isn't, consider long-term goals, is this a place that you want to work.

I’m not hiding who I am to appease anyone I don’t give a flying duck’s butt if HR hired the person that’s their business it’s not for you, me or anyone else to look up anyone’s criminal record to cause them to lose their job
